# Access StageFright API to decode JPEG from Application layer in Android

Tags: android, jpeg, decode, stagefright, opencore

Is there a way to access StageFright API's to decode JPEG image from application layer on Android 2.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Stagefright APIs are not exposed at Android Application Framework level. Android Media Player class abstracts the internal player frameworks like StageFright and OpenCore.

If you have the source code for Android, then you can use JPEG decoder present in StageFright (probably wrapped as OMX Component) through JNI.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to use stagefright apis directly from the app layer. You will have to go through the java apis. But yes, if you are ready to write the jni layers hack around a LOT of code, it is possible in principle